# Why Benard cells are usually hexagonal?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinetic-theory, convection

Solution of equations of convection (hydrodynamics equations in Boussinesq approximation) involves existence of convective cells, so-called [Benard cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93B%C3%A9nard_convection). They are represented by superposition of Helmholtz-type functions. One function gives roll, two functions give square cell, three function give hexagonal cell...

The question: why the most common cells are hexagonal ones?

Comment: Drazin and Reid (1981) is an excellent reference for questions of this nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benard convection involves fluid flow on a horizontal plane heated from below. - Scholarpedia (peer-reviewed open access online encyclopedia)

Ever since antiquity, geometers have known that only three regular polygons can tile a plane, without overlap or extra space.  These are the equilateral triangle, the square, and the hexagon.  Interference patterns on the fluid surface may be more likely to resolve as hexagons in order efficiently to fill the space.

Comment: Thank you! But why cells must cover all plane in case of convection?

Comment: I think they cover only the heated area of the plane.  Without heat there is no convection.